# Why is the if condition not met?

Tags: c, if-statement

I am writing a piece of code that is failing because of the following if the condition not working.
Please note that min=3 and range=18. Both are int.

```
if ((8 >= (min+2*range/10)) && (8 < (min+3*range/10)))
        printf("it works\n");
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. We can't tell you why that `if` isn't working, because we don't have the types or values of the variables it uses. One line of code out of context is meaningless.

Comment: what part of "Please note that min=3 and range=18. Both are int." do you not see?

Comment: What part of [Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) don't you see?

Answer (score 1):

First let's look at the first expression:

```
(min+2*range/10)
```

With the values substituted you get:

```
(3+2*18/10)
```

The multiplication and division have equal precedence and both have higher precedence, so the multiplication is done first then the division then the add.  So we have:

```
3+2*18/10 == 3+36/10 == 3+3 == 6
```

Note that the division is integer division, which means that any fractional part is truncated.  This gives us `8 >= 6` which is true.

Now we look at the second part:

```
(min+3*range/10)
```

This is identical to the last expression with a 2 put in place of the 3.  So this becomes:

```
3+3*18/10 == 3+56/10 == 3+5 == 8
```

This leaves us with `8 < 8` which is false, so the whole expression is false.

Answer (score 0):

With `min=3` and `range=18`, the first expression is:

```
(min+2*range/10)
(3 + 2*18/10)
(3 + 36/10)
(3 + 3) 
6
```

`8 >= 6` is true, so the first expression is `true`.

---

The second expression is:

```
(min+3*range/10)
(3 + 3*18/10)
(3 + 54/10)
(3 + 5)
8
```

`8 < 8` is `false`

So the if-statement fails on the second expression, and is not executed.

Comment: That is what i suspected. I want to compare 8 to a double. Typecasting did the job. Huge thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Break it into smaller pieces, assign variables to each piece and look at the variables in a debugger or print them out and you'll see where it is going wrong.

you don't need to figure out this problem, you need to learn better debugging techniques.